# Session scoped instances in TinyIoC

Tags: ioc-container, nancy, tinyioc

I need an instance of a class to be created only once per user session. How do I register such a class with TinyIoC? I'm using NancyFx.

Comment: Are you talking about per web request?

Comment: No, per user session. Meaning that it should be the same instance for all request made by a user as long as her Session object stays alive. Not too hard to implement, but I thought it's done by somebody else already.

Comment: have you looked at https://github.com/romis2012/Nancy.Sessions ?

Comment: No, thanks for the pointer! It doesn't do what I need, but I could use it for my own implementation.

Comment: If you could get hold of your static container in the session start method you could do you per session registration there perhaps

Answer (score 2):

I ended up writing the following code:

```
public static class ContainerExtensions {
    public static TinyIoCContainer.RegisterOptions SessionScoped<TRegisterType>(this TinyIoCContainer container, NancyContext context, Func<TRegisterType> factory) where TRegisterType : class
    {
        return container.Register<TRegisterType>((ctx, overloads) =>
        {
            var key = typeof(TRegisterType).FullName;
            var instance = context.Request.Session[key] as TRegisterType;
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = factory();
                context.Request.Session[key] = instance;
            }
            return instance;
        });
    }
}
```

I used the `Nancy.Session.InProc` NuGet.